# How to enable an authenticated user to vote?

Tags: 7, polls

I am new to the field . I made a drupal 7 site using theme Danland, I am able to vote for the poll as an administrator but when I login as an authenticated user I can see the completed poll and I can not vote. What do I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authenticated users probably do not have permissions to vote.

Go to administration > People > Permissions and then grant authenticated users the "vote" permissions.

Comment: Great, you can click the tick symbol below the arrow on the left to mark the question as answered.